# Condition an OHLCV 'request.security' call

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

To condition a `request.security` call, you can use the `?` operator, like this:

`C = 1 > 0 ? request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close) : 0`

But is there any way to condition an OHLCV `request.security` call?

I'm encountering a *Syntax error at input '['* error with this array format:

`[O, H, L, C, V] = 1 > 0 ? request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [open, high, low, close, volume]) : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible.

You cannot do something like below:

```
[a, b, c, d] = [open, close, high, low]
```

As a workaround, you can do:

```
[O_htf, H_htf, L_htf, C_htf, V_htf] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [open, high, low, close, volume])

O = (1 > 0) ? O_htf : 0
H = (1 > 0) ? H_htf : 0
L = (1 > 0) ? L_htf : 0
C = (1 > 0) ? C_htf : 0
V = (1 > 0) ? V_htf : 0
```